# Write to specific row after randomly getting it, PHP/mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, random

I randomly get a row from a mysql-database using php (ugly random, I know). I then want to update a specific field in the row that I get (using form or POST), but I can't seem to get it to work. I have tried to create an alias for the specific ID to use in the form-post, but that failed.

```
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT id, username, message, ttime, field1, field2 FROM table WHERE done = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

Then I want to update field1 if a specific submit-button is pressed, the important thing is that it writes to the random row (specific ID) that is fetched.

```
<?php      
 if($submit)
 {     mysql_select_db("database", $connection);
       $sql = "UPDATE table SET field1 = field1 +1 WHERE id = '???')";
       $result = mysql_query($sql);
 }
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Any takes on my problem? Thanks!

Comment: you are using prepared statements.. and you dont replace the ??? with the exact id.. or am i missing something?

Comment: I don't understand this question in the slightest.

Comment: "UPDATE table SET field1 = field1 +1 WHERE id = '???')" why are there ???, there should be the id from the row you pulled from the database.

Comment: The thing is that the ID is varying depending on what the RAND() retrieves, so it can't be absolute in the code. What I'm asking for is help to "fill in" the question marks.

Comment: Yes? And? You have the ID of the randomly selected row, because you selected it. use it.

Comment: If someone helps you out, remember to vote up their answer.  If they fixed your problem, or pointed you in the right direction, accept their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it right

```
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT id, username, message, ttime, field1, field2 FROM table WHERE done = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$query = mysql_query($query_Recordset1);
$result = mysql_result($query);
while($result = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET field1 = field1 +1 WHERE id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($result->id)."')";
    $new = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

That's just an example.

In you example, you would probably want to create a hidden field that contains the id

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $result->id; ?>" />
```

Then on your receiving page

```
   mysql_select_db("database", $connection);
   $sql = "UPDATE table SET field1 = field1 +1 WHERE id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'])."')";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the id of that random row in a hidden field in the form (`<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{id here}">`) and then use it to filter in your update (where you have the `???`). (Ideally, you would use a prepared statement for filtering and normal parameter markers.)

Alternatively, store the id in the session so it is not sent to the client, where it could theoretically be altered. So if you go with that approach, ensure there is no way somebody can alter an id he shouldn't.

Comment: But please cast the value of the hidden field to an integer in order to avoid MySQL injection!

Comment: Of course he should use a prepared statement. I don't know PHP well enough anyway, I just wanted to point out the generic way of solving such problem.